# C# Documentation <include> not found

Tags: c#, xml, documentation, xml-documentation

I have a little problem I don't understand.

I wanna document my Code using Documentation comments. And I have a XML file with information about the author who wrote the part of code.

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 and have in the Project a directory named `Documentation` there is the file `Author.xml` with this structure:

```
<doc>
  <member name="number1">
    <remarks>some Information</remarks>
  </member>
  <member name="number2">
    <remarks>some Information</remarks>
  </member>
    ...
</doc>
```

In my code I have this comment

```
/// <summary>
/// 
/// </summary>
/// <include file='~/Documentation/Author.xml'path='doc/member[@name="number1"]/*'/>
public class ExampleClass { ... }
```

but in the documentation.xml is generated:

```
<summary>
</summary>
<!-- Der enthaltene XML-Abschnitt konnte nur teilweise oder gar nicht eingefügt werden. --><include file="~/Documentation/Author.xml" path="doc/member[@name=&quot;number1&quot;]/*"/>
```

that means the XML-Code couldn't be included.

I have this from a book about C# for beginners, but it doesn't work.

Please can someone help me with my problem.

Comment: Did you ever get an answer that works?  What I'm trying to figure out is where the path needs to be relative ~from~, the location of the class I'm putting <include> in, or the location of the XML generated from the current assembly?

Answer (score 4):

> ```
>   <include file='~/Documentation/Author.xml'path='doc/member[@name="number1"]/*'/
> ```

I can see two problems with that:

1. `~` does not have any special meaning in Windows paths: you would be better using a path relative to the project.
2. You need a space between one attribute and another: change `…xml'path=…` to `…xml' path=…`.

Comment: ~/Documentation/Author.xml this is the path VisualStudio gave me and yes in my code I have the space between ...xml' path=...

Comment: @Richard, relative to where in the project? I am using '../../DataLayer/bin/Debug/DataLayer.xml' as my file, and that should be relative from my current ModelClasses.csproj, but it's still not finding DataLayer.xml

Comment: @VG1 please do not ask questions in comments: ask a question.

Comment: I apologize, I don't mean to be doing the wrong thing, but I was looking for clarification on this specific answer.  Is it not ok to ask for clarification when an answer is incomplete?  I will ask a new question if that is the case, but I thought the guidelines were ok with clarification.

Comment: @VG1, according to [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/xmldoc/include), the path is "relative to the source code file".